# SQL JOIN по полю строки с разделителем

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Есть две таблицы. Для примера я создал ситуацию мебели и материала. В первой таблице название мебели и ид материала который используется. Во второй таблице ид и название материала. Нужно приджоинить к первой таблице вторую.
Сложность в том, что может использоваться два типа материала и нужно как-то делать проверку: 1 или больше типов материалов. И если больше 1, то нужно строку делить на отдельные ИДшки и по каждой подтягивать значение и потом через запятую так же вывести. sql 12й, сплит не работает.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#111') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #111
CREATE TABLE #111
(col1 BIGINT,
name1 NVARCHAR (100),
name11 NVARCHAR (100))

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#222') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #222
CREATE TABLE #222
(col2 BIGINT,
name2 NVARCHAR (100),
name22 NVARCHAR (100))

insert into #111 (col1, name1, name11 ) Values (1, 'Стульчик',  '1');
insert into #111 (col1, name1, name11 ) Values (2, 'Стульчик 2','2');
insert into #111 (col1, name1, name11 ) Values (3, 'Стол',      '1');
insert into #111 (col1, name1, name11 ) Values (4, 'Диван',     '3');
insert into #111 (col1, name1, name11 ) Values (5, 'Стол 2',    '4');

insert into #222 (col2, name2, name22 ) Values (1, 'Дерево','есть');
insert into #222 (col2, name2, name22 ) Values (2, 'Метал','есть');
insert into #222 (col2, name2, name22 ) Values (3, 'Замша','нет');
insert into #222 (col2, name2, name22 ) Values (4, 'Стекло','нет');


select col1 as 'номер', name1 as 'Тип', name11, t.name2 as 'материал'  
from #111 as o
left join #222 as t on o.name11 = t.col2
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но если предмет будет хранить два ид материала или три через запятую:

```
insert into #111 (col1, name1, name11 ) Values (3, 'Стол', '1, 3, 4');
```

Уже джоин не отработает. А нужно получить результат:

```
номер   Тип   name11    материал
3       Стол  1,3,4     Дерево, Замша, Стекло.
```

Посмотрел на такую штуку:

```
SELECT col1, name1, (case when name11 LIKE '%,%' then 0 else name11 end) as status from #111
```

Только после then нужно придумать логику котороя будет разбивать строку на элементы, вытаскивать по каждому элеменету, сбивать в одну строку и выводить. Если это возможно.

Comment: Исправил вроде как нужно.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT #111.col1 [номер], 
       #111.name1 [тип], 
       STRING_AGG(#333.value, ',') WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY #333.value ) name11, 
       STRING_AGG(#222.name2, ',') WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY #333.value ) [материал]
FROM #111
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(#111.name11, ',') #333
JOIN #222 ON #333.value = #222.col2
GROUP BY #111.col1, #111.name1
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4a8f32077f6afc8e485de45b9fbbefa2)

Comment: Всё было б шикарно, но STRING_AGG не работает. Не подскажете, как это можно заменить?

Comment: @Brodja *STRING_AGG не работает.* С чего бы? всё прекрасно работает, и fiddle тому подтверждение.

Comment: string_split тоже например. Я гугли, это из-за уровня совместимости. Нужен 130, у меня в sql максимум 100.

Comment: Ну тогда парсите свой CSV в рекурсивном CTE, а обратно собирайте через FOR XML.

Comment: Я не знаю что это значит, но буду гуглить) спасибо большое)

Answer (score 0):

Кажется, что ваш SQL Server 2008. Выявить это очень легко:

```
SELECT @@VERSION;
```

Ваша модель данных очень сомнительна. Я изменил ее, чтобы она была правильной.
Вот ваше решение. Оно будет работать на SQL Server, начиная с 2008 года и позже.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @furniture TABLE (fur_id INT, furniture NVARCHAR (100));
DECLARE @material TABLE (mat_id INT, material NVARCHAR (100));
DECLARE @furniture_material TABLE (fur_id INT NOT NULL, mat_id INT NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO @furniture (fur_id, furniture) Values 
(1, N'Стульчик')
,(2, N'Стол');

INSERT INTO @material (mat_id, material ) Values 
(1, N'Дерево')
, (2, N'Метал')
, (3, N'Замша')
, (4, N'Стекло');

INSERT INTO @furniture_material (fur_id, mat_id) VALUES
(1, 1),
(1, 3),
(2, 1),
(2, 2),
(2, 4);
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = ',';

SELECT f.* 
    , STUFF((SELECT @separator + CAST(material AS NVARCHAR(100)) AS [text()]
             FROM @furniture_material AS fm
             INNER JOIN @material AS m ON m.mat_id = fm.mat_id
             WHERE fm.fur_id = f.fur_id 
             FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, NULL) AS MaterialList
FROM @furniture AS f;
```

**Результат**

```
+--------+-----------+---------------------+
| fur_id | furniture |    MaterialList     |
+--------+-----------+---------------------+
|      1 | Стульчик  | Дерево,Замша        |
|      2 | Стол      | Дерево,Метал,Стекло |
+--------+-----------+---------------------+
```

Comment: Ну тут вроде стала немного другая ситуация. Я этот случай  как пример придумал. Вообще есть таблица неких документов. в которых есть системный номер. По этому номеру идут связи на очень большое количество значений. Но оказалось, что за документом может быть не один номер такой. И нужно его хранить, выводить в репорте и чтобы работали связи. А тут третья табличка. Можно же придумать чтобы создавалась временка и логика для отработки Вашей логики, но там и так много обработки. Можно попробовать как вариант. Спасибо большое!